# second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I can't solve this differential equation:
$$x = y'' + e^{-y''}.$$
I can solve
$$x = u'+e^{-u'},$$
so if i go with $u=y'$, it might probably help, but it still seems to be too complex.
Is there any other way of solving?

Comment: Your question is not really phrased as a question, rather as a statement. So, what is your specific question?

Comment: But you have $y’’$ in both places.

Comment: GDumphart I couldn't get the result with my way, so i'm asking for another way of solving

Answer (score 2):

$$x=y''+e^{-y''}$$
As already said, one can solve $x=u'+e^{-u}$ which leads to a first order ODE involving the special function erf. The difficulty is the integration of $u(x)$ for $y(x)$.

Any way involves special functions. Thus it can be easier to start with a special function at the first step (In the present case the LambertW function : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html ).
$$x=v+e^{-v}\quad\implies\quad (v-x)e^{v-x}=-e^{-x}\quad\implies\quad v-x=W\big(-e^{-x}\big)$$
$$y''=x+W(X)\quad\text{with}\quad X=-e^{-x}$$
A first integration leads to :
$$y'=\frac{x^2}{2}-W(X)-\frac12 \left(W(X)\right)^2 +c_1$$
A second integration leads to :
$$\boxed{y(x)=\frac{x^3}{6}+W(X)+\frac34 \left(W(X)\right)^2+\frac16 \left(W(X)\right)^3+c_1x+c_2\quad\text{with}\quad X=-e^{-x}}$$
Note that the function $W(X)$ is multivalued in some range of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is: $$x = u'+e^{-u}$$
or
$$e^{-u}x = e^{-u}u'+(e^{-u})^2$$
using $y=e^{-u}$ and $y'=-e^{-u}u'$ we get
$$yx=-y'+y^2.$$
This is a [Bernoulli differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) wich can be solved transforming in a linear equation.

Edit: Your equation was written as $$x = u'+e^{-u}$$ and this equation can be solved as I show. Now that it's edited to $$x = u'+e^{-u'}$$, it's really what JJacquelin shows.

Comment: i wanted help with the first equation, which is x=y''+e^-y'', the second one is my attempt